# how to center align <p:notificationBar>

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

In my jsf/primefaces application I have `<p:notificationBar>` in the footer and I need to center align it. I tried setting align property for it, tried to put it inside centered aligned div but it doesnt work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `align:auto`?

Comment: "Unknown property align" is the error I get.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `margin:auto;`

Comment: If the parent is the page body, you could use margin-left:30%, or something else...i just don't see that as a good solution, but i couldn't find anything else

Comment: Any clues on this questions guys?????

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like:

```
<p:notificationBar position="bottom" effect="slide" widgetVar="bar" style="text-align: center;">  
    <h:outputText value="Example"/>  
</p:notificationBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your text:

```
<p:notificationBar styleClass="center-text"></p>
```

CSS:

```
.center-text { text-align: center;}
```

If you want to center the `<p>`, than you could use `margin: 0 auto;` , but this only works when you give along a `width`:

```
<p:notificationBar styleClass="center"></p>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

If you can not pas along a `width` because the content is dynamic or variable, you could give the wrapper a `text-align: center`, and you `<p>` a `display : inline-block` & reset the text-align.

```
<foo>
  <p:notificationBar></p>
</foo>
```

CSS

```
foo {
 text-align: center;
}
foo p {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: left; /* reset text-align center */
}
```

Comment: He is not trying to align the text, please read the question again.